# Designing UI for different screen resolutions

Tags: android

I am doing the UI designing for an app,I have included all the images in hdpi,ldpi,and mdpi drawable folders,It works pretty good for small screen resolution but having a blured image for the big screen i mean for the resolution of 480X800,How can i rectify it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are specific Android API calls that can, at runtime tell you what density and (small/large/normal) screen size a handset has. However, as a developer we should not need to worry about individual handsets at all. All we need to do is to have ldpi/mdpi/hdpi assets and small/normal/large layouts in the apk. Android internally handles everything.

Dont forget to get an indepth understanding of how Android determines which assets to use and aliasing [like this](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/07/new-tools-for-managing-screen-sizes.html).

The definitions are:

xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp.

large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp.

normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp.

small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp. (Android does not currently support screens smaller than this.)

Here are some more examples of how this works with real screens:

A QVGA screen is 320x240 ldpi. Converting to mdpi (a 4/3 scaling factor) gives us 426dp x 320dp; this matches the minimum size above for the small screen bucket.

The Xoom is a typical 10” tablet with a 1280x800 mdpi screen. This places it into the xlarge screen bucket.

The Dell Streak is a 800x480 mdpi screen. This places it into the bottom of the large size bucket.

A typical 7” tablet has a 1024x600 mdpi screen. This also counts as a large screen.

Comment: What about images loaded from the server? Is there a way to load different set of images based on screen size?

Answer (score 1):

You have to adjust your image size or resolution in each drawable folder based on the size requirement for each folder. Putting the image to each drawable folder doesn't mean it will adjust automatically.

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0):

Firstly add appropriate resolutions i.e. 32X32 48X48 64X64 128X128 and 256X256 in respective folders and if you are still getting a blurred image then change the resolution of pic in drawable folder to a high resolution image..

Answer (score 0):

You need to check image density as well .Look at Table 1 in this link and you would need to make your graphics like they say.

> xhdpi :Resources for extra high-density (xhdpi) screens (~320dpi).

[Screen Support](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Answer (score 0):

You have to include ~320 dpi images in xhdpi folder.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see some XML. Are you using 'dip' for dimensions correctly? Are you using 'match_parent' when you should be using 'wrap_content'?  Hard to tell for sure without seeing what you're trying?