# Android/Eclipse : Image matching the screen's borders

Tags: android, eclipse, layout, dimension

I'm struggling to make an image match the borders of the screen. It's a 9 patch image.
I've already asked the question  ([Android: Handling images size for multiple screens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14747489/android-handling-images-size-for-multiple-screens)) but the answers I had are not satsfying at all so I'll try asking a more general question

If I want to set different layouts according to my screen width, I create a folder for large xlarge small and normal. But how could I preview the layout in the right screen? Eclips preview are several but as it said

```
xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp
large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp
normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp
small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp
```

I don't have the same results for 2 "normal screens" 480*854 or 480*800 so how could I proceed?
I just want an image to match the layout's border I don't think it's that complicated, is it?

Answer (score 1):

In your XML file try

```
<RelativeLayout 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/border_layout"
android:background="@drawable/border"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:src="@drawable/icon1_1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

These two parameters will help you align the layout .

```
       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
       android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
```

If your border is not the parent layout then replace above attributes with these .

```
         android:layout_alignLeft="@id/border"
         android:layout_alignRight="@id/border"
```

Comment: I do not have background for my relative layout so I put nothing at android background. It does not workm the image still doesn t stretch

Comment: Then what is kind of views of your borders . Just add these two attributes 

         android:layout_alignLeft="@id/border"
         android:layout_alignRight="@id/border"
and remove alignParent layouts

Comment: by borders I mean limit of the screens

Comment: then use  android:layout_width="fill_parent"

Comment: I answered a same question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14747489/android-handling-images-size-for-multiple-screens  

Since you did not give your code so see above question . Use Weights  in linear layout and above code is also a solution . You might not getting my point

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24135/discussion-between-janshairkhan-and-morg)

Comment: My problem wat that I used a 9 patch image, while a normal image put in all the folders (ldpi mdpi xhdpi) was enough! Thanks a lot Janshair!

Comment: Thanks. If it does help then accept this as correct answer as encouragement